# iPhone/Objective - C - How to display the whole text of a long string in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uilabel

I have a very long string which is something like that below...

```
[[sqrt(221)-10,-sqrt(221)-10],[11,11]],[[rootof([[474368400,237184200,-125944810200,258530778000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)+rootof([[409681800,9099248400,-99876110400,-1875803589000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*3,rootof([[-3439170900,-50638826700,864180632700,9670592794500],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)+rootof([[1477010700,22974524100,-369910322100,-4442729593500],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*3],[rootof([[474368400,237184200,-125944810200,258530778000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*2+rootof([[409681800,9099248400,-99876110400,-1875803589000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*4,rootof([[-3439170900,-50638826700,864180632700,9670592794500],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*2+rootof([[1477010700,22974524100,-369910322100,-4442729593500],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)*4]],[sqrt(sqrt(221)+15),sqrt(-sqrt(221)+15)]
```

How can i display the whole thing in a UILabel with more than one lines (0)?

Also, although there are no linebreaks ("\n") in the string, the result is displayed like  below....

```
[[sqrt(221)-10,-sqrt(221)-
 10],[11,11]],[[rootof([[474368400,2
 37184200,-
 125944810200,258530778000],[1,
 0,-
 472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*78270
```

Any help?

PS I could upload an image but i am not allowed beacause i am a new user...

Comment: What do you want to happen? Can you give some details about how you would like the string to appear?

Comment: A good display would be if the size of each line was the same... For example, 40-50 characters in every line maybe...

Answer (score 2):

```
 textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
 textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but this doesn't change anything...
I had already "numberOfLines" zero and i had tried the wordwrap in the interface builder... :-(

Answer (score 2):

set the UILabel as a multiline

```
MyLbl.numberOfLines = xxx;
```

if you have not enough space for set the UIlabel then also set the textView As an not editable property:

```
Mytxt = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xx.0, x.0, xx.0,xx.0)];
Mytxt.transform = transform;
Mytxt.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
Mytxt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
Mytxt.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[Mytxt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:xx.0]];
Mytxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
Mytxt.delegate = self;
Mytxt.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
Mytxt.editable=NO;
```

i hope you get the answer.

Comment: I finally used a UITextView, thanks for the help. But the mysterious linebreaks remain... Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextView with auto size with non editable mode instead of UILabel (or)

```
CGSize labelSize = yourString sizeWithFont:cellFont     
constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(190.0f, MAXFLOAT); lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

This labelsize will dynamically define the label height you can assign to your label

Comment: I finally used a UITextView, thanks for the help. But the mysterious linebreaks remain... Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this code
    NSString *yourString = @"[[sqrt(221)-10,-sqrt(221)-10],[11,11]],[[rootof([[474368400,237184200,-125944810200,258530778000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])/(sqrt(221)*782707860000)+rootof([[409681800,9099248400,-99876110400,-1875803589000],[1,0,-472,884,42215]])";
    UILabel *lblNameDesc=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 10, 250, 21)];
    [lblNameDesc setNumberOfLines:0];
    lblNameDesc.text=yourString;

    [lblNameDesc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblNameDesc setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:64.0/255.0 green:64.0/255.0 blue:64.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];

    [self.view addSubview:lblNameDesc];
  //  [lblNameDesc release];
    [lblNameDesc sizeToFit];
```

Comment: The problem remains... The lines break at the same spots and the text is cut...:-(

Comment: use the height of UILabel to 21 and width less than your screen width at last [lblNameDesc setNumberOfLines:0];
[lblNameDesc sizeToFit]; I use this code so many times its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

supoose your string is. make your fond and width what ever you want:-

```
NSString longString = @"dsjkghsdkjnfgvsdjgsl,v.........................";

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(200,MAXFLOAT);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [longString  sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aial-BoldMT" size:15.0] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize   
                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, expectedLabelSize.height)];
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
myLabel.text = longString ;
```

may this will help you

Comment: expectedLabelSize.height is 0... why?

Comment: CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(200,MAXFLOAT);
 
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [result  sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aial-BoldMT" size:15.0] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize   
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
 
NSLog(@"Height is %g",expectedLabelSize.height);
display = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, expectedLabelSize.height)];   //I did not change anything... result is my NSString and display is my UILabel

Comment: what is the size you are getting??

Comment: 0. But let it go... I'm gonna use a UITextView. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
 textLabel.numberOfLines = 10; // or many that you need...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` if you want your text to be evenly distributed along several lines (so it doesn't try to break at work boundaries).

Comment: UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap doesn't apply to UITextView, right?

Comment: Yes, I think it's UILabel-only.